# How to find weekday from today's date using NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I know that I can figure out today's date by `[NSDate date];` but how would I find out today day of the week, like Saturday, Friday etc.

I know that `%w` can be used in `NSDateFormatter`, but I don't know to use it.

Comment: @Suhaib FYI!! The link is newer than this question.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* comp = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
return [comp weekday]; // 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc.
```

See [@HuguesBR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35554646/224671)'s answer if you just need the weekday without other components (*requires iOS 8+*).

```
NSInteger weekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday 
                                                   fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

(If you don't get a correct answer, check if you have mistyped `NSCalendarUnitWeekday` with other week-related components like `NSCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal`, etc.)

---

Swift 3:

```
let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())
// 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc.
```

Comment: comp weekday returns a unreal, huge number instead. . .

Comment: @coolcool1994 you might use `NSWeekCalendarUnit` insted of `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit`

Comment: On iOS8 use NSCalendarUnitWeekday instead of NSWeekdayCalendarUnit which has been deprecated. The answer is excellent though. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If someone is interested in a Swift solution, then use:

```
import Foundation

let weekday = NSCalendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())
print(weekday) // => prints the weekday number 1-7 (Sunday through Saturday)
```

See the [demo](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57f5e20c21eb825d12f20019).

**Update**: fixed to work in Swift 3

Comment: weekday is a huge #?!

Comment: @Suhaib The answer update to match latest Swift version. Thanks for mentioning the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is updated version valid for iOS 8

```
NSCalendar* currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
return [dateComponents weekday];
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version

```
NSCalendarUnit dayOfTheWeek = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:yourDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let today = Date()
let day = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: today).weekday
if ( day == 5)
    {
        yourText.text = "Thursday"
    }
```