# Get localised names of Months in iOS

Tags: ios7, localization, internationalization, nsdateformatter

My iOS application supports 6 languages. Now I want to show localized month names.

```
e.g. January in French will show "Janvier"
```

For this I have below code while converting date from UTC to local time zone

```
    -(NSString *)getLocalDateFromUTCFormattedDate:(NSString*)utcDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    NSDate *dateFromServer = [dateFormatter dateFromString:utcDate];

    // Now convert to local date
    dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale systemLocale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
    NSTimeZone* localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:localTimeZone];
    NSString *localDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromServer];
    return localDate;
}
```

But month name is still in english even after I change the language to french / japanese. 
I got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591612/how-do-i-get-weekday-and-or-name-of-month-from-a-nsdate-variable) , but I don't want to hardcode the locale. So I have used

```
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale systemLocale];
```

But no luck. Can anybody tell me whats wrong in this ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) help you for that.

[image]

Comment: I do have .strings file for every language that my app supports. So what you are saying is I need translated month names for every language , right ? Does iOS does not change the month name to the language which is selected from iOS Settings ?