# iOS : How can I indicate the Months names?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to indicate the months names , but my code just show me the number of months  like : 3 , 4 , 12

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSString *currMonth = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
month.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currMonth];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this format :

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
```

to this :

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
```

Answer (score 2):

@Mc.Lover You shoud read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) first. Check out **Managing Weekday Symbols** in that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you want the Months or Weekdays from the question?

The month:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];`
```

The Weekday:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
```

Both:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"'Weekday:'EEEE  'Month:'MMMM "];
```

I refer to this list when I need to know the formats:
http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/

Answer (score 1):

This would lead you in the right direction:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466033/127036

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about weekdays.  Your code is about months.  Confusion.

If you chase the links from the class doc you'll get to the [unicode formatting documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Also, the `stringWithFormat:@"%@"` in your last line is superfluous.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"eee"];
NSString *weekday = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
weekdayField.text = weekday;
```