# Swift compare weekday of a date with a int

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a UIDatePicker wich needs to gets validated. I want to check if the weekday from the UIDatePicker is a specific int value.

I use

```
@IBAction func validateDateTime(sender: AnyObject) {
    var date = self.dateTime.date

    let formatterWeekday = NSDateFormatter()
    formatterWeekday.dateFormat = "e"

    let weekday_string = formatterWeekday.stringFromDate(date)

}
```

to get the weekday but how can I convert it to an int so I can compare it with other int values? I tried it with:

```
weekday_string.intValue()
```

but it seems to be that weekday_string is not supporting the intValue method.

Comment: try like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2466033/2115477

Comment: I tried this too but I don't know how to write this code to swift. I'm very new in coding with os...

Comment: Jerome's answer tells you how to write this in swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringFromDate` returns a `string`. The method to convert `string` to `int` in Swift is `toInt()`

You can try:

```
weekday_string.toInt()
```

Or you can get the weekday as `int` as follow:

```
var myDate = self.dateTime.date
let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
let myComponents = myCalendar.components(.WeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate: myDate)
let weekDay = myComponents.weekday
```

Comment: @Kingalione: I suggest you use the second approach Jerome posted instead, it's less overhead: parsing a date, turning it into a string and then turning the string into an integer is pretty expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fluent enough with Swift yet, so here's an answer in Objective-C instead. Since you already have the date, you don't need to fiddle with any formatters. You just need to ask the calendar for the components:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
// components.weekDay is a number, representing the day of the week.
```

See the [NSCalendar documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html) and the [NSDateComponents documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateComponents/weekday).

To make it more stable, it's often a good idea to use a specific calendar instead of the current default calendar (users in different regions might use a non-Gregorian calendar). So instead of `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`, you'd use `[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]`.